# How do I delete multiple chats in a hybrid chat Application

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, chat, delete

I am designing a Hybrid mobile chat application. I am trying to find ways to delete list of chats.

- Android: Long press to select multiple chats and delete.
- iOS: Tap edit, select multiple chats and delete.

Which interaction should I follow?

[image: Andriod long press and delete]

Also provide examples/products if any using the same interaction.

Comment: I think the "tap edit, select chats and delete" is the best approach. By doing it like this you provide the user a button clearly visible to realise an action. As for examples I would say every iOS app uses this approach but if you want examples then just take the Camera Roll as one, there's an "Edit" button on the top right that enables the selection of albums to be deleted(one at a time because it requires confirmation). Some other apps even enable two different ways of approaching the same effect by letting you swipe left the chat and showing you a red "delete/remove/archive" button.

Comment: Sorry to continue here but I don't think this is worth an answer, I don't have enough knowledge for that. Keep in mind those two approaches are frequent on iOS Apps, I don't know if they are on Android Apps. You can also check Android and Apple guidelines for more info on the subject.

Comment: Do you plan to make your app availabel on both (or even three) platforms? If you target different platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) it might be best if you offer different interactions. So if you determine that most of the app your users are likely to use on iOS use the "tap Edit..:" version, but the corresponding apps on Android use the long press, your app might feel better for these two communities if it follows the platform preference. More work, yes, and one of the nightmares of multi-platform designs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a (now) fairly standard interaction with lists on both iOS and Android where the user can slide an item to one side to reveal contextual actions for that item.

Some interfaces even have different selections depending on which direction the menu item is moved.

Unless you are expecting your user to be deleting more than around 10 chats at once, this method should be easy enough for them to manage.

[image: Slide list item to reveal contaxtual commands]

If you *are* expecting your user to be managing more than around 10 deletes at once, then it's probably best that you allow them to enter some sort of management mode where they have access to new controls allowing them so select multiple chats and perform a single action on all chats selected - This could be in the form of an "Edit" mode as Mr.Swaggalicious has suggested in the comments.

[image]

It is important to note that each of these methods will suit different management styles - the swipe is perfect for small numbers of deletions while, for large numbers of deletions the management mode is more suitable. If you think your users may be requiring both ends of the spectrum then it's not unreasonable to include both methods.